# Getting a subgraph not crossing through a certain node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a huge (non cyclic) graph and want to find all nodes reachable by relation `X` from a given node. However, I do not want to cross a node having a certain attribute `{attr:'donotcross'}` as this represents a choke point I do not want to cross (i.e. this is the only node leading to an adjacent subgraph).

Currently I do breadth first search myself using a trivial Cypher query to isolate neighboring nodes and python, stopping the recursion as soon as I reach that specific node. This, however, is really slow and I think that using pure Cypher to isolate those nodes could be faster.

**What does the Cypher query look like returning all connected nodes via X but not traversing a node with property `attr:'donotcross'`?**

My intuition would be

```
MATCH (n)-[:X*]->(inter)-[:X*]->(m) WHERE NOT inter.attr = 'donotcross' RETURN m
```

With n being the start node. However, this does not work as this pattern can match a path with a forbidden node if there are more than the forbidden node in between the start and target node.

Comment: How many nodes have that `donotcross` attribute? And would it be feasible to change this to a label? `n:DO_NOT_CROSS` or similar?

Comment: @InverseFalcon it is not feasible to change it to a label. However, every node I am traversing has the `attr`  attribute but not all have the same value (obviously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Cypher alone, you can use the following approach:

```
MATCH path = (n)-[:X*]->(m) // best to use a label!
WHERE none(node in nodes(path) WHERE inter.attr = 'donotcross')
RETURN DISTINCT m
```

Keep in mind you should at least be using labels for your starting node `n`, if you aren't able to look them up by an indexed property for a specific label.

Also, if there are relatively few of these `donotcross` nodes, and if there is an index on the label of these nodes on `attr`, then it may be faster to first match on these nodes, collect them, then filter based on that:

```
MATCH (x) // best to use a label and index lookup!
WHERE x.attr = 'donotcross'
WITH collect(x) as excluded
MATCH path = (n)-[:X*]->(m) // best to use a label!
WHERE none(node in nodes(path) WHERE node in excluded) 
RETURN DISTINCT m
```